# Any alternatives to Spring Data Graph, jo4neo, ogrm?

Tags: java, orm, graph, spring-data-graph, jo4neo

I'm looking for easy-to-use graph DB + ORM solution. The requirements are:

1. Fluent Java interfaces, no need to use any XMLs.
2. Ease of graph traversal: "give me all entities of *these* types, starting from *this* one, traverse only using *this* set of relation types".
3. Full text search out of the box: p.2 + "only consider entities where this field contains this text"
4. No need to operate on graph level: Neo4j is great, but I'd like to avoid working with `setProperty`/`getProperty` directly.

I've already checked these:

1. ogrm - not supported anymore.
2. jo4neo - looks like doesn't work p.2 and p.3
3. Spring Data Graph - seems to be great things, but it's too immature - spent a week trying to make it work fine in Eclipse - no success.

Are there any other similar tools I need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data Graph is the most actively developed, with a recently released version 1.1.0 and lots of work planned before SpringOne in October.

However, it does create a challenge for IDEs because of the AspectJ enhanced POJOs. Have a look at the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/) for some help getting that going.

Cheers,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2015, Hibernate has started supporting neo4j:

http://hibernate.org/ogm/

Obviously, you can't query using hql, but they support using Cypher queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the very new [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) which does everything of what you want with the power of spring-data.

It also allows native queries, spatial indexes and a bunch of other cool stuff.

**Note:** It is quite immature, but still worth a look.